# How to catch the Collection sortBy keyword to variable on laravel blade?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, sorting, collections

On blade view .I resort my collection from controller
like below

```
{{$search_alls=$search_alls->sortByDesc('id')}};
```

or

```
{{$search_alls=$search_alls->sortBy('id')}};
```

The above is work fine on my blade.

I want to make a dynamic javascript button to change the keywork in the sortby  clause,or change sortBy to sobyByDesc.

How can I catch the

```
->sortBy($keywordvariable)
```

or catch the

```
->$sortclausevariable($keywordvariable)?
```

and how to  reload the new sequence $serch_alls? Can  by reload page javascript function?

Comment: You can't run php code from javascript unless you either use AJAX or reload the page.

Comment: As @AlexvanVliet stated, you cannot modify the PHP code in your blade files. Those are rendered on the server before ever getting to the client (browser). XHR requests are your friend.